# How can I extract all integer values from string using a regex?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to learn regex. I have the string:

```
$x = "5ft2inches";
```

How can I read [5,2] into an array using a regex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are assuming that the string will be of the form "{number}ft{number}inches" then you can use [preg_match()](http://php.net/preg_match):

```
preg_match('/(\d+)ft(\d+)inches/', $string, $matches);
```

`(\d+)` will match a string of one or more digits. The parentheses will tell `preg_match()` to place the matched numbers into the `$matches` variable (the third argument to the function). The function will return 1 if it made a match, of 0 if it didn't.

Here is what `$matches` looks like after a successful match:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5ft2inches
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 2
)
```

The entire matched string is the first element, then the parenthesized matches follow. So to make your desired array:

```
$array = array($matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

Comment: You should use `preg_match_all` and just use the regex `/(\d+)/` in order to handle arbitrary input.

Answer (score 2):

In Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $x = "5ft2inches";
my %height;
@height{qw(feet inches)} = ($x =~ /^([0-9]+)ft([0-9]+)inches$/);

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%height;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'feet' => '5',
          'inches' => '2'
        };
```

Or, using [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html):

```
@height{qw(feet inches)} = split /ft|inches/, $x;
```

Comment: Upvoting this and the PHP answer, because not many other languages prefix their variables with `$`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming PHP, any reason no one has suggested split?

```
$numbers = preg_split('/[^0-9]+/', $x, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: It would be better to split on what you **don't** want. See my answer (albeit in Perl).

Comment: [^0-9]+ is everything that isn't a number, which is what we don't want.

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression is simply `/[0-9]+/` but how to get it into an array depends entirely on what programming language you're using.

Answer (score 1):

With Regular Expressions, you can either extract your data in a contextless way, or a contextful way.

IE, if you match for *any* digits: `(\d+)` (*NB:  Assumes that your language honors \d as the shortcut for 'any digits'*)

You can then extract each group, *but* you might not know that your string was actually "5 2inches" instead of "6ft2inches" OR "29Cabbages1Fish4Cows".

If you add context: `(\d+)ft(\d+)inches`

You know for *sure* what you've extracted (Because otherwise you'd not get a match) and can refer to each group in turn to get the feet and inches.

If you're not always going to have a pair of numbers to extract, you'll need to make the various components optional.  Check out [This Regular Expression Cheat Sheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/) (His other cheat sheets are nifty too) for more info,

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the language you are using, so here is the general solution: You don't "extract" the numbers, you replace everything except numbers with an empty string.

In C#, this would look like

```
string numbers = Regex.Replace(dirtyString, "[^0-9]", "");
```

Comment: This doesn't fit his provided example; it would produce "52", meaning that you could not afterward determine if the original string had two integers (5 and 2) or just one (52).

Answer (score 0):

Have to watch out for double digit numbers.

/\d{1,2}/

might work a little better for feet and inches. The max value of '2' should be upped to whatever is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

```
use `/[\d]/`
```