# Using grep, how can I extract every number from a blob of text?

Tags: regex, grep

Unlike this previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1338213/4418), I want to do this on a commandline (just grep).

How can I grep *every* number from a text file and display the results?

Sample text:

```
This is a sentence with 1 number, while the number 2 appears here, too.
```

I would expect to be able to extract the "1" and "2" from the text (my actual text is substantially longer, of course).

Comment: you mean this `echo "5ft2inches" | grep -o '[0-9]\+'` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want something like this,

```
$ echo 'This is a sentence with 1 number, while the number 2 appears here, too.' | grep -o '[0-9]\+'
1
2
```

Since basic sed uses `BRE` (*Basic Regular Expression*), you need to escape the `+` symbol so that it would repeat the previous character one or more times.

Comment: Man `man` fu failed me today. Thanks - this is just what I needed.

Comment: i think the little bit explanation will help him in future. I think nothing wrong with this answer. If you post this answer before mine after my comment, i won't care about that. I won't get into fight of , 'yeh, i already suggested this in my comment' .

Comment: wait, what do you mean by similar answer? is this the same like the one that was linked by op? Yep, it's same but the answers given won't work with basic grep.

Comment: i don't know what do you mean by `don't agree`. Post a meta question about this issue..

Comment: @hwnd - It's perfectly fine to expand upon a comment that you had left in a longer answer. Why in the world would that be a problem?

Comment: @BradLarson, it's not a problem of expanding an answer that was left as a previous comment.